# Remote JUnit testing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I've been using Junit for testing in eclipse for while now, but my tests have become quite large so that testing usually takes around a few minutes in which I can't code properly due to the cpu load.

I planning to write an eclipse plugin which transfers my tests and java files to another host to have the tests running remotely and then send the results back to my own pc.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm not looking for any continuous integration solutions since I'm using a continuous testing plugin. Thanks for the first hints @Hudson :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend something like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) that can check out code from your repo, do the  builds, run the tests, and provide the reports (cobertura/code coverage as well as test results) all on the server running Hudson. This completely offloads your machine from doing any of the above.

Comment: +1 for continuous integration like Hudson / Jenkins. Having a proper build process which does not rely on an IDE is also helpful when trying to build and test externally (that is, not on the developer's workstation). Ant, Maven and the likes are very useful there.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the Remote System Explorer which is now under the Target Management project.  It has been a couple of years since I last looked at it, but the idea was to support modifying source files in Eclipse and then outsourcing the compilation steps to other machines.  This kind of thing is paramount when writing in C/C++.  That is where I would begin looking.  Good luck, this kind of thing could have great utility to the wider community.